# VideoCapture always return null image using industrial camera

Tags: c++, image, opencv, camera, video-capture

I always used VideoCapture to take frames from webcams but since I've used an industrial camera (the david laser scanner one, 3_M), VideoCapture objects always returns a null image. I've already known I have to change the ID numbers in the VideoCapture constructor but the problem still remains.

```
VideoCapture cap(0);
cap>>image; // this function return a null image
```

If I use grap and retrieve

```
bool t = cap.grab(); //returns true
t = cap.retrieve(image); //returns false
```

Does anyone know the reason why this problem happens?

I tried this new camera using both the david scanner sw and skype and it works perfectly so it should not be neither an HW problem nor an OS driver one.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe adding your OS could also help in this case.

Comment: If windows: please try to GraphStudio Next and create a toolchain where your camera is used. If that works, there might be a clue. Maybe try VLC too, if you can open your device in VLC tell us about used capture mode, settings and stuff.

Comment: Not necessarily that OpenCV should support that camera. Probably OpenCV uses FFMPEG for capturing. You should check with FFMPEG if has support.

Comment: Yes my OS is windows, thank you for advices.
I found the format of the camera and it is a y800 and surfing on google I find out opencv doesn't support it. 
Anyway Thank you for supporting me. I resolved it using AForge library (http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/) within a c# project, then I will process images through OpenCV/C++ implementing somehow Inter Process Communication and Y800 to RGB conversion too.